# Running Kafka in KRaft mode with SASL_PLAINTEXT + SCRAM-SHA-256

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl-scram

I have a working 3-node kafka kraft mode network. Everything works fine
with no authentication. I am using new Kafka 3.6.

The node_id for the kraft controllers are "1000", "1001" and "1002".

There is a regular kafka broker with node_id "1".

I am trying to move that controller configuration to "scram-sha-256"
authentication. The steps I did were:

1. With the cluster unauthenticated, I created scram-sha-256 credentials
   for users "1000", "1001" and "1002", using "kafka-configs.sh". The
   credentials reached the quorum servers and and they were distributed to
   the entire cluster, as inspection of "__cluster_metadata-0" storage
   files showed.
2. I stopped the quorum servers and I added this to the configuration of
   each one:

```
listeners=CONTROLLER://:9093

# A comma-separated list of the names of the listeners used by the 
controller.
# This is required if running in KRaft mode.
controller.listener.names=CONTROLLER
listener.security.protocol.map=CONTROLLER:SASL_PLAINTEXT

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to 
be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL


security.inter.broker.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
# KIP-631
sasl.mechanism.controller.protocol=SCRAM-SHA-256
sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256

listener.name.controller.sasl.enabled.mechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-256
listener.name.controller.scram-sha-256.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="1001" password="XXXX";
```

3. I launch the servers, that starts fine and they try to reach each
   other. Nevertheless the authentication fails with this message:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SaslAuthenticationException: 
Authentication failed during authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256
```

4. Checking with a sniffer (TLS encryption would be the next step, after
   authentication is solved) I see something strange: The client connecting
   sends the initial scram-sha-256 message, but it doesn't get the expected
   server nonce, but an inmediate authentication error.

For example, one controller send this:
`n,,n=1001,r=3mgk0fnx45exolq50iej2o3vx` (expected initial client
message) and the other replies with `Authentication failed during  authentication due to invalid credentials with SASL mechanism SCRAM-SHA-256`. It looks like the user were not recognized or the
mechanism were not supported. I would expect a server handshake as
described in RFC 5802.

Any help?. Anybody with a similiar configuration?. Anybody could share
their working configuration?. Thanks.

Comment: This is a "bug" documented here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-15513 .